# Query an external file like a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a dynamic menu generated with php/mysql like this

```
<ul>
  <li>Category 1
    <ul>
      <li>Genre 1</li>
      <li>Genre 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Category 2
    <ul>
       <li>Genre 1</li>
       <li>Genre 2</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li>Category 3
    <ul>
       <li>Genre 1</li>
       <li>Genre 2</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

To save on server requests, there is a cron job setup to print this to an external html file once a day (which is used throughout the site).

Is there away to run a mysql-like search on this multi-level ul and return results?
i.e.,

```
select 'li' WHERE genre LIKE "$search"
```

Returning the Category AND Genre.

Thank you everyone for your time and help.

Comment: Why cant you run the mysql search on the original data? You said it was generated by mysql in the first place?

Comment: The original mysql search uses 

SELECT DISTINCT(category)
followed by DISTINCT(genre) of each category.

The idea would to use it as a lighter category search function. (Hopefully faster and more efficient?)

Comment: So the real answer is just to 'cache' your result somewhere, and reuse it. Please dont try and do a 'search' on HTML list data, when you have that information available in a database.

Comment: "Hopefully faster and more efficient?" - the answer is "no" and "no" if you try and do it via the file your about to.

Comment: Yes that sound like the right redirection. Any tips on where to start for that? Run a search on cache results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will preface by saying all the comments encouraging you not to do this are correct. You should be doing this in the database. Seriously, **DON'T DO IT THIS WAY!**

*But*... If I pretend there's no database involved and we're simply trying to tackle parsing the HTML structure a little *like* a database, per your request, I'd try jQuery. I'd make a function that looks this:

```
function list_search(query) {
    var results = $("li:contains("+query+")")

   if (results.parents('li').length > 0) {
      return results.parents('li');
    }else{
      return $("li:contains("+query+")");
    }
```

This is fine-tuned particularly for your list structure — if you had lists a third-level deep or more you'd have to revisit it. If you do a query for "Category 3" it'll return that `<li>` element with the sub-list. If you do a query for "Genre 2" you'll get the `<li>` elements for each of the categories, as each in your example contains a "Genre 2" item, which I think is the behavior you were looking for.

Obviously that's a client-side solution, which may not help if you're trying to do this on the server with cron-jobs and whatnot. It looks like you're using PHP based on the tags. Conveniently enough there's a nice library called [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) based on jQuery that we could transfer this to pretty easily:

```
    $document = phpQuery::newDocumentFile('badidea.html');

    function list_query($query) {  
      $result = pq('li:contains('.$query.')');
      if (strlen($result->parents("li")) > 0) {
        return $result->parents("li");
      }else{
        return $result;
      }  
    }
```

FWIW the Github version of phpQuery seems to be about 2 years ahead of the Google Code version. The `->parents()` method doesn't seem to be in the example on the Google Code site so I'm not sure it's supported, but it works with the Github version.

So... I hope you find a way of tackling this problem from the database and that this example otherwise satisfies your curiosity.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing reply. Sometimes it good to know the wrong way to do things to understand the better way. Great advice.